# VBA httpWebRequest with Credentials

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get some data from a cloud service.

This is my code so far:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Call GetHTTPResult("https://venice.unit4.com/WebConnect/api/ZZKlesserRob/2017/Balance/GetBalance?AccountNumber=604&BeginMonth=1&EndMonth=1", "username", "password")

End Sub

Function GetHTTPResult(sURL As String, Optional username As String, Optional password As String) As String




Dim XMLHTTP As Object, sResult As String

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

username = "dummy"
password = "dummypass"

XMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic" & Base64Encode("username" & ":" & "password")
XMLHTTP.Send

Debug.Print "Status: " & XMLHTTP.Status & " - " & XMLHTTP.StatusText

sResult = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
GetHTTPResult = sResult

Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Without the credentials it gives me the **"401 - Unauthorized"** -response, which is good, I suppose.

However I do have the necessary credentials at my disposal but I can't seem to fix the problem posed by the `Base64` encoding.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From inspecting the [docs](https://venice.unit4.com/WebConnect/Help/RequestHeader) I believe your are missing a `space` in your `Authorization` header:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/xml");
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + Base64.encode ("User:Password"));
```

So your should read:

```
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(username & ":" & password)
```

Also, you should add an `Accept` header to the request with `application/xml` or `application/json` to specify the format of the requested data.